# For some reason when I write getparams it doesn't do what it is supposed to do?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

This is what is meant to happen:
[image]

and when you just write "getpar" it is meant to give the option:
[image]

however for me when I do it
[image]

nothing happens

and it throws an AuthFailureError

```js
package com.name.name;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by p on 17/06/2016.
 */
public class RegisterRequest extends StringRequest {

    private static final String REGISTER_REQUEST_URL = "http://name.comli.com/Register.php";
    private Map<String, String> params;

    public RegisterRequest(String name, String username, int age, String password, Response.Listener<String> listener) throws AuthFailureError {
        super(Method.POST, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
        params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("name", name);
        params.put("username", username);
        params.put("password", password);
        params.put("age", age+ "");

       getparams
```

Thankyou and help would be appreciated into how to resolve this error.=)

Comment: There is no getParams method. In the first example you're typing it outside of any method so the IDE suggests creating getParams method. Second exmaple you're typing inside a constructor so the IDE would autocomplete a method call but there is no getParams method. Bottom line, look where you're writing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what it seems you are typing it in the constructor. Try typing it out of the constructor? And I dont really know what you are trying to do. To me it looks like there is a function, and in the next picture the function is gone suddenly but there is an autocomplete for it.

So are you sure your parent class has the getParams function? And is it public or protected? My knowledge on inheritance isnt that great anymore, but I remember having problems with private functions.

As you can see this is your code

```
public RegisterRequest(String name, String username, int age, String password, Response.Listener<String> listener) throws AuthFailureError {
    ....

   getparams
```

But the bracket never closes! So try this:

```
    public RegisterRequest(String name, String username, int age, String password, Response.Listener<String> listener) throws AuthFailureError {
        super(Method.POST, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
        params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("name", name);
        params.put("username", username);
        params.put("password", password);
        params.put("age", age+ "");
}
```

And then type getparams. I dont know if it works, but atleast you have a closed constructor.

Comment: Sorry but what does it mean by typing it out of the constructor

Comment: @CatherineLagoon do you know what a constructor is? Also, why are you throwing an AuthFailureError

Comment: No I don't as I'm new to coding

Comment: Ah well there we go haha, it is nice to have some knowledge about the language before diving into really making an app. Here: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/class_constructor.html So when your constructor bracket closes, try typing getparam.

Comment: See what I added in the answer. Try that.

Comment: Thankyou for your help =)